# Android - Losing scope on UI elements after onDestroy()

Tags: android, android-activity, ondestroy

I am trying to handle problems that occur in my application when the phone is plugged into certain types of chargers and put into "Car Mode" or "Driving Mode".

In the running application, onDestroy() is called and immediately followed by onCreate(), and the application starts again normally.  However, subsequent calls to update UI elements (in the newly created main Activity) now have no effect, and it looks like I've lost scope on my layout.

```
    RelativeLayout splash = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.splash);
    splash.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

What could be ocurring onDestroy() that I'm not accounting for?  I don't do much cleanup onDestroy because I didn't think I needed to.

Comment: I got the same issue. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The `Activity` has been detached from the UI by the time `onDestroy()` is called so having UI calls to it doesn't make any sense.  If you need the splash to be shown, set it to `View.VISIBLE` in `onCreate()`, `onResume()`, or **maybe** `onPause()`.  I'm not entirely sure if `onPause()` would act any different.

Comment: Sorry, the UI calls I'm referring to occur in the new Activity after the new call to onCreate

Comment: In that case, are you calling `setContentView()` to instantiate a new instance of the layout?  The old one is part of the old `Activity's` context and has been destroyed, so you need a new one.

Comment: Yes I'm calling setContentView() again, I'm not doing anything different from how I would normally instantiate the main Activity

Answer (score 0):

When the phone rotates the activity is destroyed and recreated. Plugging into a car charger usually forces the phone to landscape mode, thus rotating it (from portrait, most likely) and calling `onDestroy`. There is a way to prevent this behavior with some activity flags -- but Google advises against it.

We need to see some more code for this Activity to figure out what's going on.

Also, as DeeV points out, the activity is long gone by the time onDestroy gets called, so it might not be the right place to be doing whatever it is that you're doing -- but we need more code to be sure.

As a sidenote, sliding the keyboard up (on phone's that have slideout keyboards) will produce the same effect.

Comment: Yes, I've seen this behavior in the past.

I have changed my main activity so that splash is not a layout that is shown, but a new activity in itself.  I am still seeing issues though, in that after my app has been onDestroy()/onCreated, a call to finishActivity(AppState.ACTIVITY_SPLASH) has no effect.